# How to install custom ROM on Android after increasing system partition?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, custom-roms

I wanted to install a GSI image on Redmi Go, but the GSI image size was 2 GB and the system partition on the device is 1.3 GB, so I followed [this guide](https://iwf1.com/how-to-re-partition-your-android-tablet-or-smartphone-all-options-included-change-size-fs-type-etc) to increase the system partition. I increased the system partition by decreasing the userdata partition. After all of that, I flashed the ROM and rebooted it, then it shows the MI logo and power off itself.

I tried repartitioning multiple times, but the issue was the same. I was able to flash stock ROM via fastboot using the MI flash tool and the partitions also went back to stock.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *"**Warning**: Re-partitioning your Android may lead to a complete breakage of your device software and may render it unbootable!  Do NOT engage unless you know what you’re doing."*

Comment: [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/testers-wip-flashable-zip-to-increase-system-partition-solving-gapps-error-70.4032451/#post-83795769) might help